# Check if a textbox value is a string or a number in javascript

Tags: javascript

Basically I have the following code:

```
<input type="text" value="123" id="txtbox">
<script>
var myVar = document.getElementById('txtbox').value;

if (myVar.substring) {
alert('string');
} else{
alert('number');
}
</script>
```

No matter what value you put in the textbox, it will always alert `string`. Is there a way that if you put a number in the textbox it will alert `number` instead of string? Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`value` on `input` elements is **always** a string. It might be a string of digits.

If you want to know whether that string only contains valid numbers, you have to parse it (and decide what you consider a valid number, and allow for that).

For instance, you'll get people telling you to use `parseInt(myVar)` or the unary `+` (`+myVar`) or `isNaN(myVar)` (which does what the unary `+` does) or `Number(myVar)` (same), **but**:

1. `parseInt` only parses the beginning of the string, `parseInt("345foo")` is `345`
2. `parseInt` is, of course, only for whole numbers; you'd want `parseFloat` for numbers with fractional portions
3. All of those will fail to understand thousands separators
4. All of those will fail to understand a decimal separator that isn't `.` (e.g., in many locales it's `,` or sometimes even a space)
5. `+myVar` and `Number(myVar)` and `isNaN(myVar)` and such will treat an empty string as `0`

...that kind of thing. So you have to do some prep on the string according to what input you want to accept.

Once you've decide what format(s) to handle, there are a dozen questions with answers here about doing the actual parsing:

- [*How do I Convert a String into an Integer in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript) (note that's integer-specific)
- [*What's the fastest way to convert String to Number in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862624/whats-the-fastest-way-to-convert-string-to-number-in-javascript)

Comment: why ParseInt and not isNaN like @KJ Price ?

Comment: you can use typeof to detect type of variable in js, then you can see as @T.J. Crowder said that `alert(typeof(document.getElementById('txtbox').value));`   always return string

Answer (score 5):

is `isNaN` (literally "is Not a Number"):

```
var myVar = document.getElementById('txtbox').value;

var myNum = +myVar;//as suggested by T.J. 
if (isNaN(myNum)) {
   alert('string');
} else{
   alert('number');
}
```

Comment: This will, of course, fail for numbers with thousands separators in them, or decimal separators that aren't the `.` (in many locales it's `,`), etc., etc.

Comment: Yep, true that @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Also, an empty string will evaluate as a number, won't it?

Comment: @jpw, I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder again good call. I made the change you suggested.

Comment: @KJPrice According to the examples on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) _the empty string is converted to 0 which is not NaN_

Comment: Ah, @jpw good call. When testing `isNaN('')` it returned false and my brain short-circuited by the double negative. You are totally right.