# issues with isNan function

Tags: javascript

I have a text box and button where a User must input a mark between 1 and 10. After such inner HTML displays the mark as a percentage.

I am having a bit of difficult getting my`isNaN` function to work within my code for numbers that exceed 10 or for values that are indeed not numbers.

The code works well except for this specific part and I am wondering where I am going wrong.

```
<script>

    function myFunction() {

        var x, text;

        // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
        x = document.getElementById("numb").value;

        // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 10
        if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 10) {
            text = "Input not valid";
        } else  {
            text = "Your final mark is";
        }



        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (x) * 10 + "%";
    }

    </script>



<body>

    <h1>JavaScript to Validate Input</h1>

    <p>Enter your mark between 1 and 10:</p>

    <input id="numb">

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>




</body>
```

Comment: What isn't working? What result are you getting that you don't expect?

Comment: Side note: You're relying on *implicit* conversion from string to number. Your `x` will contain a string (the value of `value` is always a string). It just happens that everything you're doing with `x` (`isNaN`, `<`, `>`, and `*`) will all implicitly convert for you, but if you'd done `x + something`, it wouldn't have. I suggest *explicitly* parsing the string to a number, up-front, where you get it from `.value`. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30032514/157247) gives some of your options for doing that.

Comment: yes so it will acknowledge the Isnan but if I input 12 which is above the range of the function, it still executes the calculation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if`-`else` logic is working correctly (provided you first coerce your string `x` to a number using the unary `+` operator); the problem is that you're not doing anything with your `text` variable. You should only be adding the percentage to your `text` when the input is valid, like so:

```js
function myFunction() {

  var text

  var x = +document.getElementById("numb").value

  if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 10) {
    text = "Input not valid"
  } else {
    text = "Your final mark is: " + (x * 10) + "%"
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = text
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>JavaScript to Validate Input</h1>
  <p>Enter your mark between 1 and 10:</p>
  <input id="numb">
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (x) * 10 + "%";` inside the `else` block

```js
function myFunction() {

        var x, text;

        // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
        x = document.getElementById("numb").value;

        // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 10
        if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 10) {
            text = "Input not valid";
        } else  {
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (x) * 10 + "%";
            text = "Your final mark is";
        }
        console.log(text);



        
    }
```

```html
<body>

    <h1>JavaScript to Validate Input</h1>

    <p>Enter your mark between 1 and 10:</p>

    <input id="numb">

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>




</body>
```