# Javascript format is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm wanting to format numbers based on keypress / ng-change. After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript), I though I would be able to use some of the sample code to format my numbers with a fixed precision. The code works fine when called on page load and written out to the browser, it does not work when I apply the same code to the value of a text field on key press.

```
function GetChar (event){
    var theValue = document.getElementById('foo').value;

      document.write(theValue.format(2, 3, '.', '.'));
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bullrout/jkr64670/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added a function to `Number.prototype`, but your variable `theValue` is a `String`.

You should convert the value to a `Number`. There are [several ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12862627/859640) to convert a `String` to a `Number`. One way is to use the `Number()` function, like this:

```
var theValue = Number(document.getElementById('foo').value);
```

You should also use `onkeyup` because the typed key will not yet be included in the value of the input element during the handling of `onkeydown`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mxavnL0g/1/)

Comment: Your sir are a legend! Thank you very much.