# jquery if else compare query issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below jquery if\else comparison to evaluate part of code based on results,

```
if($('#order_quantity').val() < $('#available_quantity').val()) {
   // ---code to run----
} else {
   // --- code to show error---
}
```

This code work 3-4 times correctly for inputs and after that it working wrong,

when `$('#order_quantity').val() = 5` and `$('#available_quantity').val() = 46`, then ideally **--code to run--** should execute but it is running **--code to show error --** of else statement.

Sometimes it correct and sometimes it not, I created `console.log` for above input values, inputs are correct but still comparison results throw wrong results

What can be problem in this comparison?

Comment: I think you want to parseInt or use Math.Round to get the desired value..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values read from the *DOM* are **strings**. You need to convert it to numbers in order to use it in arithmetic operation unless the operator coerces the operand to number.

```
if(+$('#order_quantity').val() < +$('#available_quantity').val())
```

You can convert string to number using

1. By preceding the string with unary `+` operator, this will coerce the string to Number.
2. By using `Number` function
3. Using `parseFloat`
4. Using `parseInt`, but this will convert the float value to integer.

---

> this code work 3-4 times correctly for inputs and after that it working wrong

The code works for some values because how the strings are compared.

```
> "5" < "46" // false
```

The strings are compared character by character just like how sorting works. In this code the comparison is done as `'5' < '4'`, when comparing the strings their ASCII values is compared. As the ASCII value of `5` is greater than that of `4` the comparison returns `false`.

Answer (score 5):

`val()` returns a string. You have to convert these string values in numbers:

```
if(Number($('#order_quantity').val()) < Number($('#available_quantity').val())) {
     // do something
} else {
     // do something
}
```

An example when your expression fails:

```
"24" < "124"
false
```

There are other ways to convert strings into numbers (see [What's the fastest way to convert String to Number in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12862624/1420197)):

- `Number(x)`
- `parseInt(x, 10)` (for integers)
- `parseFloat(x)`
- `+x`;
- `~~x` (for integers)
- `x | 0` (for integers)

...or using `Math` methods. `x` is the string value.

Comment: yeah, `"1" < "2"` returns `true`. But, `"2" < "112"` returns `false`

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev That's because that is the behaviour of strings. It is compared using the character by character basis. So in the second example is translated as  `'2' < '1'` and as the ASCII value of 2 is greater than that of 1, the condition returns `false`. Hope that makes sense. This problem is also observed when sorting the numbers, there also you've to explicitly convert the string to number before comparing

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev Yes, for the same reason why `"a" < "b"` is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to convert string to integer as all values read with jQuery val() method are returned as strings.

You can also use this code -

```
if(parseInt($('#order_quantity').val()) < parseInt($('#available_quantity').val()))
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of `$('#order_quantity').val()` is *string*. `'5' > '46'` is `true` just like `'b' > 'a'` is `true`. To convert string value to int value, you can use *parseInt* function. To get the intended result your code should be something like:

```
if (parseInt($('#order_quantity').val()) < parseInt($('#available_quantity').val()))
  {
    //---code to run----
  }
else
  {
    //--- code to show error---
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try these solution :**

```
var order_quantity =  $('#order_quantity').val();
var available_quantity = $('#available_quantity').val();

if( Number( order_quantity ) < Number( available_quantity ) )
{ //---code to run---- }
else
{ //--- code to show error---}
```

[Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

**Or**

```
if (order_quantity - available_quantity  < 0)
{ //---code to run---- }
else
{ //--- code to show error---}
```

This forces javascript to process a numeric calculation. Strings will be converted into numbers.