# Adding together numbers displayed as strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am pulling some JSON data and trying to calculate a totals fee. However, the data coming in from JSON are shown as strings. Is there a way I can convert these into numbers AND calculate these together in the same code block?

Here is my Javascript code:

```
result.data.bkor_payamount = result.data.bkor_subtotal + result.data.bkor_handling + result.data.bkor_discount + result.data.bkor_adjustment + result.data.bkor_bookingfee;
```

Here are my JSON fields

[image]

This is what is currently produces!:

[image]

**UPDATE**
This seems to have done the job

```
 result.data.bkor_payamount = +result.data.bkor_subtotal + +result.data.bkor_handling + +result.data.bkor_discount + +result.data.bkor_adjustment + +result.data.bkor_bookingfee;
```

Comment: Convert strings to numbers using `parseInt(string)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to convert a number to a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: `parseFloat(string)`

Comment: `Number(string)`, `+string`. Just use Google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the fastest way to convert String to Number in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862624/whats-the-fastest-way-to-convert-string-to-number-in-javascript)

Comment: The +string option appears to be the quickest and easiest, as edited.

Answer (score 2):

Most elegant way I found to do this :

```js
var resultJson = {
  "key1" : "40.00",
  "key2" : "30.00",
  "key3" : "20.00",
  "key4" : "10.00",
  "key5" : "40.00",
  "key6" : "10.00",
  "key7" : "50.00",
  "key8" : "60.00",
  "key9" : "40.00",
};

var sum = Object
           .keys(resultJson)
           .map(function(key){
               return parseFloat(resultJson[key]);
            }) // This generates [40,30,20,10, etc. ]
           .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0); // This sums up all elements in array

console.log(sum)
```

Comment: I think it should be `parseFloat`. He is dealing with money it seems, and in his example it just so turned out that they all end on ".00", but I don't think that *has* to be the case

Comment: I hesitated. You're right, I changed to parseFloat.