# Basic JavaScript function returns concatenation and not arithmetic sum

Tags: javascript

I am new so thank you for your patience.
I did search a lot for the answer but couldn't find, maybe because it's too obvious.

In this case the inputs x and y are taken from `<input type="number"..`

This function executes upon button click.

Can you tell me why it returns a concatenation, e.g. 33 instead of 6, 45 instead of 9.

```
  function sum(x,y) {
       x = document.getElementById("x").value;
       y = document.getElementById("y").value;
       var answer = x+y;

       document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = answer;

  }
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Because the values you're getting are strings and you need to cast them to numbers. There has to be a million dupes of this question on SO alone. Looking for one now...

Comment: .value always returns a string. So tell JS to interpret it as number by e.g. using ....value * 1 or parseInt, or parseFloat, or...

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert it into number.

```
function sum(x,y) {
   x = document.getElementById("x").value;
   y = document.getElementById("y").value;
   var answer = Number(x)+Number(y);

   document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = answer;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when you put a string on either side of the `+` operator, it performs concatenation.

```
"3" + "3" // "33"
```

The value property of an input will always give you a string.

[Convert the strings to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862624/whats-the-fastest-way-to-convert-string-to-number-in-javascript) if you want to add them together.

Comment: The value property of an input will always give you a string. - odd when input type is "number", innit.
Thank you, that explains the issue!

Answer (score 1):

This happens beacuse `x`and `y` are Strings, to proper operate with them use `Number(x) + Number(y)` or `parseFloat(x) + parseFloat(y)`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `parseInt` function to actually convert the strings to ints and then add them like this

```
function sum(x,y) {
   x = parseInt(document.getElementById("x").value);
   y = parseInt(document.getElementById("y").value);
   var answer = x+y;

   document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = answer;

}
```