# How to get value of checkbox in 0/1 instead of true/false reactive forms angular4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I have worked on angular4 project and I have a requirement where I need to get the value of checkbox in 0/1 instead of true/false. I mean if checkbox is checked then it will return 1 otherwise return 0. If anyone know the solution please guide me, thanks in advance.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="status" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can cast a `boolean` to `number` in this way:

1. `+` operator: `+var`
2. `Number` constructor as function: `Number(var)`
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29543818/4099454

```js
const success = true;
const failure = false;

console.log('success: ', success, '=>', +success);
console.log('failure: ', failure, '=>', +failure);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add it:

```
 (change)="status = $event.target.checked ? 1: 0"
```

Like:

```
 <input type="checkbox" 
   (change)="status = $event.target.checked ? 1: 0"
   name="status "
   [(ngModel)]="status ">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input 
    type="checkbox" 
    checked="checkbox_checked" 
    [(ngModel)]="checkbox_checked"
    (change)="checkbox_checked ? state = 1 : state = 0">
```

.ts

checkbox_checked: boolean;

state: number;

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it work but only with ngForm [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Gwj9ROW4nYF9p0GxwCgK?p=preview). On latest version it doesn't bind to value at all probably bug.

```
<input type="checkbox" (ngModelChange)="status = $event ? 1 : 0" [ngModel]="status" />
```

Comment: Its not  working, I have tried this, but on uncheck its not set value 0.

Comment: @TarnjeetSingh updated but only with ngForm and its somehow its buggy on latest verion