# JavaScript --->How can i convert an array of strings to an array of numbers?

Tags: javascript

**My code**

```
  var bills = [50.23, 19.12, 34.01, 100.11, 12.15, 9.90, 
               29.11, 12.99,10.00, 99.22, 102.20, 100.10, 6.77, 2.22 ];

  var totals = bills.map(function(tip){
     tip += 15/100;
     tip = tip.toFixed(2);
     return tip;
  });
  console.log(totals);
```

**RETURNS**

```
  [ '50.38', '19.27', '34.16', '100.26', '12.30', '10.05', 
   '29.26', '13.14', '10.15', '99.37', '102.35', '100.25', '6.92', '2.37' ]
```

**Now, How can i convert this string array into an numbers array like this**

```
  [ 50.38,  19.27, 34.16, 100.26, 12.30, 10.05, 
   29.26, 13.14, 10.15, 99.37, 102.35, 100.25, 6.92, 2.37 ]
```

Comment: toFixed converts a number to a string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the fastest way to convert String to Number in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862624/whats-the-fastest-way-to-convert-string-to-number-in-javascript)

Comment: is the tip 15 %? or a fixed value, like 0.15 ?

Comment: This is kind of an X->Y question.  You currently convert your array of numbers to strings via .toFixed.  You could wait until you are about to display those numbers before using .toFixed, not halfway through a series of calculations, where you might still need the values to be Numbers for future operations.

Comment: remove `.toFixed(2)`. Like magic, they'll be numbers again.

Answer (score 0):

**Coerce the return value** to a `Number`, Replace

```
return tip;
```

with ***unary plus* `+`**

```
return +tip;
```

or **`Number` constructor**

```
return Number(tip);
```

You can shorten your code to

```
var totals = bills.map( tip => +( tip + 15/100 ).toFixed( 2 ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

You could loop through the array and use the parseFloat() function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat