# I cant calculate numbers with dot fraction like 2.5

Tags: javascript, math, numbers, calculator

I am doing a javascript calculator but I have problem with calculating fraction numbers.

```js
dot.addEventListener("click", function(){
    result.textContent = result.textContent += ".";
})
```

```js
if (divideActive == 1 ) {
    divideActive = 0;
    const showenResult = result.textContent;
    result.textContent = parseInt(finalResult) / parseInt(showenResult);
    console.log(finalResult);
    console.log(showenResult);

}
```

when i type 2.5 / 1 it says 1 or 2.5*2 = 4 it just calculates before dot.

Comment: Well what do you think parseInt does? You need to use parseFloat or Number

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862624/whats-the-fastest-way-to-convert-string-to-number-in-javascript

Comment: That is true sorry for my disturb

Answer (score -1):

well actually you can go with finalResult/showenResult and convert result to string with toFixed(2) function.

```js
let value = 5;
let divider = 2;
let result = value/divider
let resultStr = result.toFixed(2)
console.log(resultStr)
```